# generate all possible subset from a character array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I need to generate all possible subset from a character array in MATLAB with reduced execution time.
For example:
input='ABCA'; 
output ='A',
'B',
'C',
'AB',
'BC',
'CA',
'ABC',
'BCA',
'ABCA'

Comment: 'ABA', and 'ACA' are not valid substrings. I need linear scan over the input. I  want the unique substrings. I mentioned the reduced execution time, since the input is of length 500 characters.

Comment: yes they are not valid substrings. Is this possible to generate substrings with maximum length of 20 characters?

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can find all these subsets using straight-forward loops. I don't know if it is worth-while vectorizing these, as any vectorization will require large intermediate arrays.

With a random input of 500 characters, and `maxLen` at 20, I got 4207817 unique substrings. It took my computer (with MATLAB R2017a) 12 seconds to find these. Whether that is fast enough or not is up to you, but I would not bother further optimizing this.

```matlab
input = 'ABCA';
maxLen = 4;

subsets = {};
for len = 1:maxLen
   subs = cell(1,numel(input)-len+1);
   for start = 1:numel(subs)
      subs{start} = input(start:start+len-1);
   end
   subs = unique(subs);
   subsets = [subsets,subs];
end
disp(subsets)
```

Output:

```
'A'    'B'    'C'    'AB'    'BC'    'CA'    'ABC'    'BCA'    'ABCA'
```

If it is important to preserve the order of the substrings, then add the `'stable'` argument to the `unique` call:

```matlab
   subs = unique(subs,'stable');
```

For example, for `input = 'AFCB';`, the output without `'stable'` is:

```
'A'    'B'    'C'    'F'    'AF'    'CB'    'FC'    'AFC'    'FCB'    'AFCB'
```

and with `'stable'` it is:

```
'A'    'F'    'C'    'B'    'AF'    'FC'    'CB'    'AFC'    'FCB'    'AFCB'
```